# Getting the node icon from tree view in SAP GUI Scripting

Tags: sap-gui

I want to automate the FEBAN transaction.  Once the tree view is loaded, I am able get all the nodekeys.  But I want to get the image/icon along with the text to identify whether its successfully posted or not.  I tried getabapimage, getnodeabapimage methods and iconname property.  But I am unable to fetch it.  Where am I going wrong how to fetch the icon details in GUI Scripting.

Edited:-

I have included the FEBAN screen print.  I have also included the code that I used to fetch the text details.

[image: FEBAN Screen Print]

Thanks.
Subramanian S.

Comment: If it's an icon within a text field (at the beginning of the text), it means it's stored in the first 4 characters with special identification, e.g. `@1E@`. They are automatically converted to an icon. You can find [here the IDs of the icons](https://experience.sap.com/files/guidelines/icons_sap/index.htm).

Comment: @SandraRossi -  Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately its not part of the text.  But it shows a square filled with green or red based on posting status.  I have to dig further.

Comment: Difficult to help without a screenshot... EDIT: I realize that I had the same issue with an "Item Tree", alas I couldn't get the icon code before the text with `GetItemText`, so maybe you experience the same issue with nodes.

Comment: Even we can try with the menu tree in the initial login page.  I am unable to fetch the image